# How can I use snmp++ to enable/disable a switch port?

Tags: c++, snmp, snmp-trap

I've been looking for this for a long time on the web,but I only found out that i can use snmp trap to achieve this function.But I don't konw how to use trap in snmp++.I only can find how to use trap in net-snmp,but our teacher ask us to use snmp++.So if somebody can help me about it, I will very thank for it

Comment: Please post complete code and try to edit your question specifying exactly what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that in order to enable/disable port you have to toggle **ifAdminStatus** which is defined in IF-MIB.

**Interface UP:**

```
snmpset -v1 -c community hostname IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.interface i 1
```

**Interface DOWN:**

```
snmpset -v1 -c community hostname IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.interface i 2
```

There is a nice set of examples including *snmpset* that comes with SNMP++ library. So you should be able to modify this sample app accordingly in order to implement what you need.

Comment: ifAdminStatus (1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7) is a read-only OID, you shouldn't be able to set it this way.

http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7